# SharePoint Online2013 Team Site Deleted

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, auditing, item-deleted

I created a DevGroup for myself and a new admin that is coming on board.  That site is now mysteriously gone.  I didn't delete the site, and no one else has access to do so.  Is there an audit where I can go back and find out what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have auditing enabled then i think you can check. check this article for more details: [Search the audit log in the Office 365 Security & Compliance Center](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Search-the-audit-log-in-the-Office-365-Security-Compliance-Center-0d4d0f35-390b-4518-800e-0c7ec95e946c#siteadminactivities)

But if you want to restore that deleted site collection than follow these steps.

- Sign in to Office 365 as a global admin or SharePoint admin.
- Select the app launcher icon  The icon that looks like a waffle and
  represents a button click that will reveal multiple application tiles
  for selection. in the upper-left and choose Admin to open the Office 
  365 admin center. (If you don't see the Admin tile, you don't have
  Office 365 administrator permissions in your organization.)
- In the left pane, choose Admin centers > SharePoint.
- On the ribbon, click Recycle Bin.
- In the Recycle Bin, select the check box next to the site collection 
  that you want to restore.
- On the ribbon, click Restore Deleted Items.

[Restore a deleted site collection](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Restore-a-deleted-site-collection-91C18651-C017-47D1-9C27-3A22F325D6F1)

Comment: There is nothing on that page.  It says no site collection was found.

Comment: is Tenant admin delete the site collection? if it is gone from that recycle bin then you have to contact the support for restore...they have 14 days retention,

Comment: I can get to the site via the URL, and it still shows up under the "Following" quick launch on our SharePoint home page.  But the tile is not listed anymore with all of our other tiles.

Comment: can you search the site on the admin center? is it site collection or subsite

Comment: Let me preface the next comment with I'm about 14 days new to SharePoint with absolutely no prior experience.

Under Admin -> SharePoint -> Site Collections, none of the pages I've create (3) exist there.